# Words in different languages in the url

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have a website in 3 languages. I only have one page with the code and I change the text for each language.

Just a simplified example of the same page in English and French:

> myDomain.com/tap.php/?lang=en
>   myDomain/tap.php/?lang=fr

To clean the url I use:

```
RewriteRule (myDomain)\/(\w{2})\/(.*) $1\/$3.php?lang=$2
```

This redirects the pages from:

> myDomain/en/tap
>   myDomain/fr/tap

This works well but my question is: **Is it possible to have words in different languages in the url?** For instance, if some user writes in French:

> myDomain/fr/robinet
>
> *Note: "robinet" is "tap" in French*

could it be redirected to:

> myDomain/tap.php/?lang=fr

(Remember that I just have 1 page for both languages, so `myDomain/fr/robinet.php/lang=fr` does not exist. I could make another redirect from that last to `myDomain/fr/tap.php/?lang=fr` but it doesn't seem like a very efficient solution) Maybe the solution is not in the `.htaccess`?

So my question is: how do you use words in different languages in the url?

Comment: Are you going to make a RewriteRule for every word in EN and FR ?! Redirect users based on ip or browser lang and give them the option to choose a different lang, store that choice in a cookie.

Comment: I think you are thinking too far into this. I doubt many users will actually blindly start typing in pagenames in the URL bar. (And even if they did, a "page not found" should be acceptable for them)

Comment: @Dark: probably you are right. What about Google? I  thought It would help in search in each country? Key words in url are important.

Comment: @Nrc if your url is just a redirect, it wouldn't be indexed by Google anyway. You can improve your SEO in other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems pretty simple, in order to not affect performance, make sure you put your rewrites in order they are going to be called from most to least, also use the last rewrite flag on the rules.

```
RewriteRule (myDomain)\/(\w{2})\/(.*) $1\/$3.php?lang=$2 [L]
RewriteRule myDomain/fr/robinet myDomain/tap.php?lang=fr [L]
```

If you want to automate it though, you'll need to do this on the application logic, with some kind of routing. For example in laravel you would have your controller for the file, say `TapController`, and then you will define your routes with some kind of map that points each word to each controller.

```
Route::get('/{lang}/{word}', function($lang, $word){
    $map = [
        'tap' => 'TapController@'.$lang.'index',
        'robinet' => 'TapController@frindex'
    ];

    return App::make($map[$word]);
});
```

The above may not be valid code, haven't used laravel in quite a while, but it is just to illustrate my idea.

Eventually you could use a rewrite map.

Comment: You guess that url doesn't look correct, isn't it ?

Comment: Are you sure that to do a second RewriteRule is a good solution? I would need a RewriteRule for each word-file !. In relation to the automate option that sounds good. Can you suggest a simplified example or where to begin, please?

Comment: I have no idea of Laravel. I just do not understand

Comment: @Nrc then just go with the first method, it is not going to affect your performance unless you put in like 10000 rules and the server has to get to the 10 thousandth one.

Comment: I suppose that your second RewriteRule is with "?" and not "/" You wrote: myDomain/tap.php/lang=fr

Comment: @Nrc yeah, I just copied it from your question, before the edits